# What's the difference between MemberInfo FieldInfo

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am writing an extension to get Description and other attributes from an `Enum`.
I have seen examples using `FieldInfo` and others using `MemberInfo`. Can someone explain what the difference is and when it would make a difference which one I should use?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `Enum`? Why do you need reflection here? Please provide some further information and some short code that shows what you want to achieve.

Comment: @HimBromBeere it sounds like they want to decorate enum values with `[Description("more context here")]` and access that information at runtime; in which case reflection is entirely correct and appropriate; the enum values are essentially described by static const fields (`FieldInfo`).

Comment: Yes, I am also looking at adding custom attributes as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MemberInfo` is the abstract base-class for both `FieldInfo` and `PropertyInfo`. So when you want to access a field use `FieldInfo`, for properties take `PropertyInfo`.

EDIT: To get attributes set on your enum-values you may use this:

```
var attr = typeof(MyEnum).GetField(myEnumValue.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Description), false);

if (attr.Length > 0) return attr[0].Description;
```

In this case you could also use `GetMember` instead of `GetField` as `GetCustomAttributes` is defined on `MemberInfo` and therefor provided on both `FieldInfo` and `PropertyInfo`.

Answer (score 4):

*FieldInfo* class is derived from *MemberInfo* class and it has additional methods/properties that are specific only for fields. *MemberInfo* class is more general, it can describe constructors, properties, methods, events and not only fields.

I assume that some people use *FieldInfo* and some *MemberInfo* depending on requirements. In some cases information provided by *MemberInfo* are enough and in some not.